# Could not connect to amazon my sql rds using php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, relational-database

I am connecting amazon rds to make web services using php but it does not connect to the servers here is my code

```
<?php

try{
$dbhost = 'myrds.cjahuqpumuov.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306';
$username = 'myname';
$password = 'mypassword';
$dbname = 'mydb';

$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysql_select_db($dbname);

}

catch(Exception e){

echo e

}
?>
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE in /home/content/i/h/u/ihus235/html/cs/pah_brd_v1/productivo/selectTest.php on line 17

Error Trace

```
 Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 110 in /home/content/i/h/u/ihus235/html/cs/pah_brd_v1/productivo/selectTest.php on line 12

 Warning: mysql_select_db() [function.mysql-select-db]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/content/i/h/u/ihus235/html/cs/pah_brd_v1/productivo/selectTest.php on line 13

 Warning: mysql_select_db() [function.mysql-select-db]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/content/i/h/u/ihus235/html/cs/pah_brd_v1/productivo/selectTest.php on line 13
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the host name with port number is only not allowing you to connect.. Try by removing port number like :

```
$dbhost = 'myrds.cjahuqpumuov.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com';
```

I also faced the same problem few days before.

Comment: showing same problem Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE in /home/content/i/h/u/ihus235/html/cs/pah_brd_v1/productivo/selectTest.php on line 17

Comment: have you tried with `http://` before. `http://myrds.cjahuqpumuov.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`

Comment: yes host name is correct which i am using in my file

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

try{
$dbhost = 'myrds.cjahuqpumuov.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com';
$username = 'myname';
$password = 'mypassword';
$dbname = 'mydb';

$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $username, $password, $dbname, 3306);
mysql_select_db($dbname);    
}
catch(Exception $e){    
echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";    
}
?>
```

Comment: added the echo 0f $E in question upadted please check

Answer (score 0):

```
dbhost = "hostname:port"; //default is 3306    
$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $username, $password);
```

You need to pass port number with hostname.

Comment: i am not using ec2 its rds amaozon

Comment: yes , sorry i am also talking about amazon rds. see this is how i am using rds amazon db:
    `define('_E_DB_PRIMARY', 'enterprise-db-dev.xyz.com:3306');
    define('_E_DB_USER', 'enterprise_dev');
    define('_E_DB_PASSWORD', '');
    define('_E_DB_DATABASE', 'enterprise_dev')`

Comment: `<?php

try{
$dbhost = 'myrds.cjahuqpumuov.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306';
$username = 'myname';
$password = 'mypassword';
$dbname = 'mydb';

$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($dbname);

}

catch(Exception e){

echo e

}
?>`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
For me the problem was resolved by changing selinux flags

https://serverfault.com/questions/240015/how-do-i-allow-mysql-connections-through-selinux

I hope this is helpful for you too